# How NOT to join insider program

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider, msdn

I'm replacing a hard drive with a new one, and device I might as well go to a newer Windows 10   22H2 Pro.  (I was on 1903..?)

These are MSDN ISO's and keys.  As I understand it, they are essentially identical to regular retail versions.

So I started a fresh install, and turned off EVERYTHING during the install process. And did not create an account on Microsoft ("use with limited features" or something like that)

Then tried to disable the auto windows updates, because I have been shot in the foot more than once by MS pushing an update and breaking something. So I want to pick which updates I installed, like Windows 7 allowed. (Also their penchant for rearranging and hiding options and settings is super annoying - sorry one more rant)

But I am seeing two messages:

```
This PC does not meet minimum system requirements to run Windows 11
```

(good... I don't want it)

And under "Advanced Options" -> "View Configured Update Policies" it says (see image)

"Examples Include"

- Your organization has set some policies to manage updates"
- You have opted in for the Windows Insider Program"

How could I if the installed doesn't have an MS account associated with it?

Also, is shows "Policies set on your device"

[image]

Questions:

- Is this an indication that the new Windows 10 install is in the
  insider program?
- If so, where during the install do I NOT allow that to happen (as I
  said, I'm rather confident I switched off everything)
- Or is this just deceptive example text and I am not in the program?

Also, if this is not a correct but abbreviated understanding, please let me know:

*The insider program pushes new stuff down on the user, and will eventually end up mutating your machine into a Windows 11 OS.  And as those things are slowly installed, there is no way to get rid of them.*

Thanks for any feedback anyone provides.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Edition listed under Settings > System > About > Windows specifications will tell you if you have a Windows Insider build installed.

If you have a Windows Insider Build installed, and:

- Installed Windows 10 from an ISO
- Didn't add it to any Windows Domain with a server that can potentially push policies to you)
- Didn't join The Windows Insider Program on this computer (by clicking *Get started* in Settings > Update & Security > Windows Insider Program)

Then, the ISO you downloaded was a Windows Insider ISO in the first place. Windows Insider isn't an "option" while installing from a regular Windows ISO (and it also doesn't matter if your Microsoft Account has joined Insider, since this is a per-computer settings.)

If you still have the ISO or the direct download link to it you can check/search the file hash to see what it is.

Comment: It has 4 entries, none of which say "insider"...  Edition Windows 10 Pro, Version 22H2   Installed on 5/21/2023,  OSBuild 19045.2965,  Experience Windows Feature Experience  Pack.   So it appears I am "safe" :-)  the ISO I used isn't an "insider".  I don't even recall seeing anything like that from the MSDN anyway.

Comment: @SpacemanScott - "I don't even recall seeing anything like that from the MSDN anyway" - Windows Insider ISOs are not distributed through MSDN.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this an indication that the new Windows 10 install is in the insider program?

The only polices you currently have configured, is that Windows will notify you of Windows Update downloads and you have configured Automatic Windows Update. If you want to remain on Windows 10 22H2 until it's no longer supported and replaced with a version that is supported, you will want to enable the following group polices:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"TargetReleaseVersion"=dword:00000001
"ProductVersion"="Windows 10"
"TargetReleaseVersionInfo"="21H2"
```

Worth pointing out, cumulative updates released for Windows 10 22H2 will still be automatically installed, as the group polices you have enabled will not block them from being installed. The polices I have suggested will only allow you to remain on Windows 22H2 until it's no longer supported.

> The insider program pushes new stuff down on the user and will eventually end up mutating your machine into a Windows 11 OS. And as those things are slowly installed, there is no way to get rid of them.

This is partially inaccurate.  A Windows 10 machine opted into the Insider Preview program absolutely would not result in your machine being upgraded to any Windows 11.  At this time, upgrading to Windows 11 is optional, and configuring `ProductVersion` to "Windows 10" would allow you to remain on Windows 10 until it was no longer supported.

Comment: When use GPEDIT and set "configure Automatic Updates" to disabled, it's still pushing updates on me.   And that page says "Get updates for other MS products"...   When I enable it and set it to 2, it STILL pushes updates on me (i.e. it *still* tells me it has to reboot to apply the new patches)...  *DAILY* ??!!  That terrifies me, since I've had those updates screw up my PC.  Anyway to stop it?  So I can control and select what to be pushed onto me?

Comment: When I say "terrifies me", this brand new HD and install already gave me a BSOD when trying to shut down.  A message about "Windows Failed" to do something...   And a frown -->   :-(   and "will try to restart" for me.   So far, only once (in the second day)

Comment: @SpacemanScott - "it's still pushing updates on me." - Yes, I know it is, which is why I indicated that the policy won't block Windows Updates. Your question wasn't about blocking cumulative updates delivered through Windows Update.  You asked if you had inveterately installed a Windows Insider Preview build on your system. **There actually isn't a group policy that will block cumulative updates in their entirety.**